# angular.js:10126 Error: [ng:areq] Argument [....] is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs

Hopefully any can help me with this error.

I'm trying to create a controller as follows:

**myController.js**
 Controller for partial 'partial_test.html' code not shown for convenience

```
console.log("Loading custom JS file");
console.log("Angular Module: " + angular.module('AppModule'));
angular.module('AppModule')
   .controller('myController', ['$http', '$scope',  function ($http, scope) 
      console.log("******   Building the controller  *****");
   }]);
console.log("Module value: " + angular.module('AppModule'));
```

**Main App.html** 
Has its own controller (MainController) code not shown for convenience

```
<HTML>
   <head>
      ...
   </head>
   <body ng-app='MainController'>     
      ...
     <script src="webjars/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

     .... angularJS ...App.module declaration...etc...

<div ng-include=" 'custom-scripts.html' "></div>    ** <<< Tricky part**

 </body>
</html>
```

**custom-scripts.html << HTML FILE!**

```
<!--  This file is the place where app can include custom script files dependencies. -->

<script src="custom/js/myController.js"></script>

<script src="custom/js/any_other_libray.js"></script>
```

**app-route.js (Just relevant code)**

```
when("/testMe", {
            templateUrl: 'testCustomFeature/partial_test.html',
            controller: 'myController',
            titleKey: "My Test",
            access: {role: 'any', appRole: 'any'}
        })
```

When I deploy/run access app.html in browser's console I'm able to see from myController.js:

> Loading custom JS file
>   Angular Module: " + [object]
>   Module value:  [object]

This makes me think that the file is being loaded/executed but when I navigate to partial_test.html (defined in app-route.js) I get the following error:

```
angular.js:10126 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'myController' is not a function, got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.28/ng/areq?p0=myController&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined
    at http://localhost:8080/myproject-webui/webjars/angularjs/1.2.28/angular.js:78:12
    at assertArg (http://localhost:8080/myproject-webui/webjars/angularjs/1.2.28/angular.js:1509:11)
    at assertArgFn (http://localhost:8080/myproject-webui/webjars/angularjs/1.2.28/angular.js:1519:3)
    at http://localhost:8080/myproject-webui/webjars/angularjs/1.2.28/angular.js:7312:9
    at link (http://localhost:8080/myproject-webui/webjars/angularjs/1.2.28/angular-route.js:907:26)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:8080/myproject-webui/webjars/angularjs/1.2.28/angular.js:6752:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:8080/myproject-webui/webjars/angularjs/1.2.28/angular.js:6146:13)
    at publicLinkFn (http://localhost:8080/myproject-webui/webjars/angularjs/1.2.28/angular.js:6042:30)
    at boundTranscludeFn (http://localhost:8080/myproject-webui/webjars/angularjs/1.2.28/angular.js:6166:21)
    at controllersBoundTransclude (http://localhost:8080/myproject-webui/webjars/angularjs/1.2.28/angular.js:6773:18)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:10126(anonymous function) @ angular.js:7398nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:6755compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6146publicLinkFn @ angular.js:6042boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:6166controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:6773update @ angular-route.js:865$broadcast @ angular.js:13093(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:547wrappedCallback @ angular.js:11682wrappedCallback @ angular.js:11682(anonymous function) @ angular.js:11768$eval @ angular.js:12811$digest @ angular.js:12623$apply @ angular.js:12915done @ angular.js:8450completeRequest @ angular.js:8664xhr.onreadystatechange @ angular.js:8603
```

**So this is the application flow:**

```
App-route.js - > defines navigation and partial config.  
App.hml -> has MainController
App-hmtl -> load custom-scripts.html via ng-include <<KEY Part I guess>>
custom-scripts.html -> load myController.js
App.thml -> navigates to partial_test.html -> relies on myController definition
Then Error is shown
```

.

Why my controller is never created. Is it due the fact that  ng-include creates a new scope?

**Note:**  if I include the myController.js in app.html using a `<script>` tag it work fine. and shows "** Building the controller **" message. Which is logged out in myController.

I just want to know what Angular is doing here and why the error rather than judging the implementation.

Thanks in advance,

Jose

Angular Newbie

Comment: By "at runtime" what do you mean? What page are you trying to load?

Comment: Hi Thomas, first thanks for  commenting!
By run time I mean, deploying/running  navigating to App.hml in the browser 
I did some edit to clarify a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<body ng-controller = "myController">
```

in mainapp.html

Comment: Thomas, 
App.html ins the main page which has its own controller.

Answer (score -1):

If the type is undefined, make sure any newly added controllers/directives/services are properly defined and included in the script(s) loaded by your page.

[docs.angularjs.org](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/areq?p0=CustomController&p1=not%20a)